# Ruby: accessing elements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have output of the form

```
{\"id\":\"anon\",\"source\":\"abc\",\"word_count_message\":\"There were 268 words\"}"
```

stored in variable `x`

I need to access the field "word_count"

```
x.inspect
```

prints

```
"{\"id\":\"anon\",\"source\":\"abc\",\"word_count\":268}"
```

`x["word_count"]` prints `word_count` instead of `"There were 268 words"`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to go through this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Then, share some code and clearly explain what is the problem you need help with.

Comment: What is the source of this data? What is the data type (`x.class`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
h = JSON.parse(x)
puts h["word_count_message"] to get the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's cleaner ways to accomplish this, but this works:

```
h = Hash[x.tr('"{}\\', '').split(",").collect{|kv| [kv.split(":")[0], kv.split(":")[1]]}]
```

I took out the double quotes, brackets and extra `\`'s. Then I split it into an array using the commas as the delimiters. Then I changed each element of that array into a 2-element, key/value array using the `:`'s as delimiters. Then I turned the whole thing into a `Hash`.

```
p h
p h["word_count_message"]
```

Output:

```
{"id"=>"anon", "source"=>"abc", "word_count_message"=>"There were 268 words"}
"There were 268 words"
```